# Linux & SVN: How to remove all versioned files but KEEP directory structure, ignore .svn dirs?

Tags: linux, svn, find, recursive

I want to remove all the versioned files from my repository, but KEEP the versioned directory structure. Obviously I want to leave all the .svn directories untouched.

In other words, I want to completely empty a working copy's directory structure WITHOUT harming the directory structure itself.

For example, removing the files from this structure:

```
dir/
    .svn/
        [files]
    svsubdir1/
        file1
        .svn/
            [files]
    subdir2/
        file2
        file3
        file4
        .svn/
            [files]
        subsubdir1/
            file5
            .svn/
                [files]
```

Should result in:

```
dir/
    .svn/
        [files]
    svsubdir1/
        .svn/
            [files]
    subdir2/
        .svn/
            [files]
        subsubdir1/
            .svn/
                [files]
```

I'm looking for some sort of `find` command or something to accomplish this, and I'm having trouble constructing the command. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is that I have a web app which has been developed in "versions" but has never been under revision control before. I want to put it under SVN revision control now, and for ease of historical reference, etc., I'm trying to replicate a progression of four versions from four different "backup" folders containing progressively older versions. Once the files are deleted, I can copy the newer files into the hierarchy to simulate the newer revision. Not sure if all that makes sense. :)

Comment: It is worth noting that SVN since version 1.7 (October 2011) no longer has multiple ".svn" directories, but just one .svn dir at the top level. See http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
find dir/ -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -type f -print
```

should fit the bill (mostly comes from the find manpage for `-path`).  Pipe it to less and check it out.  What it does is first find (path ends in .svn and don't recurse into (prune) this directory) or (if it's a file, print it).

If it looks good, change it to

```
find dir/ -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -type f -exec rm {} +
```

The + version sticks all of the files together into one rm command.  If you're paranoid, keep a backup of the tree (`cp -a dir/ otherdir/`) first.

Comment: Perfect solution, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks Derf!

Comment: In place of '-exec rm {} +' you can also use the more intuitive '-delete' option.

Comment: @Tim According to the find manpage, `-delete` is depth-first and therefore conflicts with `-prune` because the files inside the folder would be checked before the folder itself was examined.  The other solution (using `-not -path ...` rather than `-path ... -prune` can use the -delete option.

Comment: Nice catch!

Comment: I've used this trick (or similar) numerous times over the years in a variety of scenarios. So thanks again, @DerfK. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -not -path "*/.svn/*" -and -type f -and -exec /bin/rm '{}' \;
```

Ought to do the trick.

Comment: Just a tip, but instead of `-exec /bin/rm '{}'` you can use `-delete`.